# Linux script input parameters generator - recommendation?

Tags: linux, scripting, input, arguments, command-line-arguments

I'm looking for a tool to generate a script for handling input parameters.

I guess it would be best if the script would generate a file that I will later include (source) in my main script. This way, if the parameters requirements are changed, the generator can still be used without erasing the content of the main script.

It would also be nice if the tool would generate a help section with all the input parameters possibilities.

Any knowledge of such a tool?

**Update:**
Looking for a (ba)sh script generatorr, though I don't really care - as long as I can interact with it from a script (sh) file.

Comment: I don't see `getopts` being difficult enough to write a generator for...

Comment: What programming language?  (First recommendation: if you're even asking this question in the first place, it's time to give up on (ba)sh.)

Comment: Are you looking for something like gflags (has translations into many languages by now (python, etc))? http://code.google.com/p/google-gflags/

Comment: Looking for a (ba)sh generator, though I don't really care - as long as I can interact with it from a script (sh) file.

Comment: There is a standard in Linux, right?

Comment: Example: command [-a|--all] [-b] [-tag tagname] file1 file2...